# OAuth2, retrieve data from Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-search-console

The why
I'm working on a plugin that is supposed to interact with the Google Analytics, and figured that the google-api-php is the best way to do that.
I have not used a couple of hours of research and testing diffrent stuff - and i feel like i'm still stock at the beggining, so i hoped maybe somebody on SO could help a bro out :)
I have looked at every possible example i could find, read alot of stuff - but i seem not to be able to find a working example i can study.

**So what is your plugin supposed to do?**
What im look to do is;

1. Connect with Google Analytics from my webpage
2. Queue for diffrent data (clicks, links, country - the usual stuff)
3. Use diffrent kind of stastics on that data

If anybody either have a working examply i can study (i learn best by studying working code), or willing to help me out in anyway - i would appreciate it alot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_. It's not at all clear what you're asking above, can you edit your question to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The developer documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) provides a fair example on how to get started. Please try to run the example and if it works then you can follow the reference guide [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference). I hope this helps! If there is anything else you need just let me know.